# Sorting the std::list of structures by rule

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, stdlist

I have a `std::list<struct Data> data`. I need to sort `data` by `head` in according to the rule `rule`.

For this I am using `std::list::sort(Compare comp)`.

The implementation below works, however it is inefficient. Finding the element in the `rule` list requires traversing the list, calculating the distance requires traversing the list again.

How else can data be sorted? Maybe use a vector, unordered_map and other?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Data {
    std::string code;
    std::string text;
    std::string head;
};

int main() {
    struct Data data1{"0010", "it is text1", "head3"};
    struct Data data2{"0025", "it is text2", "head1"};
    struct Data data3{"0065", "it is text3", "head2"};
    struct Data data4{"0011", "it is text4", "head2"};
    
    std::list<struct Data> data = {data1, data2, data3, data4};
    
    std::list<std::string> rule = {"head1", "head2", "head3", "head4"};
    

    data.sort([&rule](const Data& first, const Data& second) {
        auto index_a = std::distance(rule.begin(), std::find(rule.begin(),rule.end(),first.head));
        auto index_b = std::distance(rule.begin(), std::find(rule.begin(),rule.end(),second.head));
        return index_a < index_b;
    });
    
    for (auto &it : data)
        std::cout << it.code << "\t" << it.text << "\t" << it.head << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more verbose with the issue you're having with that sorting method's efficiency?

Comment: Aside: you don't need `struct` in `std::list<struct Data>`

Comment: as you need random access to the list `std::vector` will probably give you better performance

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, inding the element in the rule list requires traversing the list, calculating the distance requires traversing the list again.

Comment: Please put that into the question, not here as a comment!

Comment: You might cache the distance in an hash map (`std::unordered_map`).

Comment: Side note: Your data has no "head4" but "head2" twice. How should this cases be handled?

Comment: 1. Precompute the rules' positions and keep them in a table; 2. Avoid `std::list`. There are a few situations where linked lists are good, but they are very rare.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrote the program using a `std::vector` and `std_unordered_map`.

Changed the speed of the functions `std::list::sort` and `std::sort`:

without flag `-O3`:

- 1st option: 0.000030 s
- 2nd option: 0.000017 s

with flag `-O3`:

- 1st option: 0.000009 s
- 2nd option: 0.000009 s

Two questions:

1. Is everything correct?
2. How can I apply `set::less<std::string>` when sorting?

   ```
    std::vector<struct Data> data = {data1, data2, data3, data4};

    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned> rule = {
        {"head1", 0},
        {"head2", 1},
        {"head3", 2},
        {"head4", 3}
    };
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(),
              [&rule](const Data& first, const Data& second) {
        int index_f = rule[first.head],
            index_s = rule[second.head];

        return index_f < index_s;
    });


    for (auto &it : data)
        std::cout << it.code << "\t" << it.text << "\t" << it.head << "\n";

    return 0;
   ```

   }

Answer (score -2):

This issue can very easily be fixed by using a container that provides random access like `vector`, `deque` or `array`. For these, calculating the distance between two iterators is an O(1) operation, not an O(n) operation. In addition, they may reduce memory overhead and improve locality of reference which isn't covered in the Big O notation but still affects performance.

Another part to look at is the `find()` call though, because that still requires traversing the sequence in O(n). If you used some kind of dictionary like `map` or `unordered_map` you could reduce this to O(log n) or O(1) even.

Lastly, if it's not just coincidence that you want the order to be "head1" ... "head4", you could simply delegate to `less<string>` instead of implementing your own.

**HOWEVER**: Unless you have actual numbers that prove that this code is the bottleneck in a performance-critical application, you are doing premature optimization. Also, all Big-O claims start with "There is a `n_0` so that for all `n > n_0` ..." and you may not even reach `n_0` with all that.